# Changing menu background of toolbar with material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Hi I want to change the style of my menu background, with the popupTheme it doesnt change

My toolbar code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/fondoNavigation"
     android:theme="@style/CustomToolbar"
     android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/letraNavigation</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomToolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/letraNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/letraNavigation</item>
</style>
```

My v21 Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/letraNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Any findings? Have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this one I changed the background and others things

```
 <style name="CustomToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/letraNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/letraNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/fondoNavigation</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.Dbtools_style" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Title Text Color -->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/DimGray</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
    </style>

  <style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/DarkGray</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/White</item>
    </style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_bar</item>
        <item name="background">@color/title_bar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Be carefull, this code have differents behaviour when using on api > 21 and api < 21

Answer (score 0):

Solution for people not using Support Library

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:background="#e53935"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopUpTheme"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material" />
<style name="ToolbarPopUpTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"/>
```